# so the .cshtml doesn't see app_code by defaul

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

I thought `app_code` folder was there so that the razor knows where to look for classes and the likes but it seems I still need to add `@using`.

What's the purpose of `app_code` folder then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ASP.NET web site (as opposed to a web application), including Web Pages, can only access classes that are in the `App_Code` folder.

Your problem is most likely that you have added a namespace to your classes, so you must use `@using`.

If you leave out the namespace in your `App_Code` classes then you won't have to use `@using`.

Comment: on! yeah. removing the namespace makes it work. so the namespace is hiding everything?

Comment: It's not hiding everything, but if you aren't `using` that namespace then you can't access things in that namespace unless you fully qualify things in the namespace, eg. `namespace.mymethod()`.